# How to bring JavaScript array data from .js file into .jsp file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jsp

I have a JavaScript file that prompts a form. After the user fills the data and clicks on "submit", the data will be stored in a JavaScript array.

How can I retrieve/display this array from the .js file in my .jsp file?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = [];

    //data filled will be stored in array called table[]
    $("#send").click(function() {
        var kpiName = $("#kpiName").val();
        var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
        var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
        var value = $("#value").val();
        var unit = $("#unit").val();

        if (kpiName === "" || startDate === "" || endDate === "" || value === "" || unit=== "") {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else {
            table.push({
            kpiName: kpiName,
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate,
            value: value,
            unit: unit
        });

        $("#contactdiv").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: You have the array in client side, why not display it directly using jquery..?

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by *retrieve in jsp*? jsp is run in server. Do you want to send the data to server and recreate the page..?

Comment: How can i directly display in on my jsp using jquery? @t-j

Comment: First of all, there is no `jsp` in client (*browser*). You have the resulting `HTML` page as well as the array on client. If you want to display the data in the `HTML` page, use jquery to manipulate the page as you wish - stuff like `$(".nameIAarray").text(array[0].name)`. Or let me repeat the question, do you want to send the data to server..?!